# python json throughs Key Error even though there doesn't seem to be anything causing it

Tags: python, json, add-on, keyerror, bpy

I'm having trouble loading data from a json file in my blender add-on, it's throwing me a fatal error and I don't know how to fix it. I looked up the error multiple times but the problems never apply to my code, can anyone help me fix it?

this is the json file (default.json)

```
{
    "viewport": "solid",
    "lighting": {
        "type": "studio",
        "lighting file": "Basic",
        "world space lighting": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    },
    "color": "OBJECT",
    "background": "THEME",
    "backface culling": false,
    "x-ray": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "shadow": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "cavity": {
        "enabled": true,
        "type": "world",
        "ridge": "${BindValue: RIDGE}",
        "valley": "${BindValue: VALLEY}"
    },
    "depth of field": false,
    "outline": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "specular lighting": false
}
```

this is the function to load it

```
def loadPreset(location):
    with open(location) as json_file:
        print(json.load(json_file))
        data = json.load(json_file)

        with data["lighting"] as lighting:
            if lighting["type"] == "studio":
                bpy.context.space_data.shading.light = 'STUDIO'
                bpy.context.space_data.shading.studio_light = lighting["lighting file"]

                with lighting["world space lighting"] as world_space_lighting:
                    bpy.context.space_data.shading.use_world_space_lighting = world_space_lighting
                    if world_space_lighting:
                        bpy.context.space_data.shading.studiolight_rotate_z = world_space_lighting["rotation"]

        bpy.context.space_data.shading.color_type = data["color"]
        bpy.context.space_data.shading.background_type = data["background"]
        bpy.context.space_data.shading.show_backface_culling = data["backface culling"]

        bpy.context.space_data.shading.show_xray =  data["x-ray"]["enabled"]
        if data["x-ray"]["enabled"]:
            bpy.context.space_data.shading.xray_alpha = data["x-ray"]["alpha"]
```

and this operator to call it

```
class VPM_DP_DEFAULT(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "default"
    bl_idname = "view.default_display"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        data.currentViewport = "default"

        import pathlib

        loadPreset(str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()) + "\\viewportPresets\\basic\\default.json")
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

but when I click the button linked to the operator, it gives me this error...
[image]

I looked around to see how to fix this, the problem is usually checking for a key that doesn't exist, but my code never checks for a key called 'presets'

Comment: The stack trace shows you which code is looking for a key called "presets".

Comment: Is the `json.load` coming from the built-in json module or a different implementation?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The stack trace says that the call to `json.load` is the problem, which (as far as I know) can't be true unless it's a custom implementation. The built-in json module doesn't care about the content of the data.

Comment: as a hack, you could add a random key:val : "presets": "something" or "presets": {everything_from_your_json}... and see what happens. but mainly, i'd follow Kemp's idea

Comment: In that case, though, the stack trace ought to step into that call. My guess is that the code was modified (for debugging purposes) after initially running into the error, but an older version of the module is still loaded, so that when the traceback is printed, Python grabs the wrong source code. Fixing this cleanly may require restarting the interpreter completely.

Comment: "I looked up the error multiple times but the problems never apply to my code" Did you try specifically putting `blender json presets` into a search engine?

Comment: It may be unrelated to your error but does 1) `with data["lighting"] as lighting:` and 2) `with lighting["world space lighting"] as world_space_lighting:` work in your code?  These same like invalid with statements to retrieve and assign values from a dictionary.

Comment: @Kemp no, I used "import json", I should have the python built in one